# JSTL code not works with Apache Tiles

Tags: jsp, jstl, apache-tiles

I check if the current URL ends with '/' then the variable `slash` is empty. Else the `slash` is '/'.

```
<c:set var="slash" value="/"/>
<c:set var="uri" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}"/>
<c:if test="${fn:substring(uri, fn:length(uri)-1, fn:length(uri)) == '/'}">
   <c:set var="slash" value=""/>
</c:if>
```

Next, basing on the variables `slash` and `uri`, some text is appended to the current URL and the new link is build.

```
<a href="${uri}${slash}${cd.toString()}/">${cd.toString()}</a>
```

It was working when the code was on the same page where the new URL is build. When I applied Apache Tiles, the first code is put into main.jsp:

```
<body>
<c:set var="slash" value="/"/>
<c:set var="uri" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}"/>
<c:if test="${fn:substring(uri, fn:length(uri)-1, fn:length(uri)) == '/'}">
   <c:set var="slash" value=""/>
</c:if>

<div id="headerId">
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</div>
<div id="bodyId">
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
</div>
</body>
```

and the link are build in content.jsp:

```
<a href="${uri}${slash}${cd.toString()}/">${cd.toString()}</a>
```

But in content.jsp the variables `uri` and `slash` are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not to do with Tiles. You'd hit the same problem even using <jsp:include …/>

<c:set …/> by default puts variables into page scope.
You'll need to do the following to have those variables available in the next page as well

```
<c:set var="slash" value="/" scope="request"/>
```